scrollable grid with custom layout
I need to build a layout with grid which should be something like the below image:

what I've done so far is:


.horizontal-scroll-container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 230px);
  grid-template-rows: 153px 153px;
  gap: .5rem
}

.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.grid-item:nth-child(1),
.grid-item:nth-child(5n + 1) {
  grid-row: 1/ 3;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background-color: red
}
<div class="horizontal-scroll-container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 3</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 4</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 5</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 6</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 7</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 8</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 9</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 10</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 11</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 12</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 13</div>
    <div class="grid-item">Item 14</div>
  </div>
</div>



It does create the first part if I have 7 items but when I increase the items it does go like column not repeating in a row.
Also I should say that each item has 230px width and 153px height but first and every 7th item has twice the width and size of the normal item.
Edit1: one way that it does what I want is to make the grid parent element flex and direction row and repeat the grid but I think it doesn't the right way because for example I want to fetch items from an API which is like 100 items and it doesn't make sense...

Update your code like below and you don't need the extra wrapper.


.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 230px; /* all columns width equal to 230px */
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 153px); /* 2 rows */
  grid-auto-flow: column; /* column flow */
  gap: .5rem;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.grid-item {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.grid-item:nth-child(7n + 1) {
  grid-row: span 2; /* take 2 rows */
  grid-column: span 2; /* tale 2 columns */
  background-color: red
}
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 6</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 8</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 9</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 10</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 11</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 12</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 13</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Item 14</div>
</div>



